# Сравнение данных в таблице

Tags: html, python, django

Есть модель:

```
class Vacation(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField() 
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

Не могу понять, как с помощью цикла осуществить проверку на пересечение диапазонов дат из разных строк. 
Вижу такую логику: взять start_date из первой строки и сравнить со значениями start_date и end_date остальных строк. 
И так каждую последующую строку.

Пример.
Имеем таблицу вида:

```
id fio start_date end_date
1 вася 07.01.2018 21.01.2018
2 петя 01.01.2018 14.01.2018
3 миша 01.06.2018 14.06.2018
```

и т.д.
Надо проверить что 01.01.2018<07.01.2018<14.01.2018
если да, то "отпуск васи пересекается с отпуском пети"
далее проверяем с мишей и т.д.
потом берем вторую строку - мишу и его так проверяем. 
итого найдем все пересечения отпусков

Comment: Что-то непонятно. Что и для чего нужно сравнивать? Можно поподробнее описать в чем задача?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров
Добавил уточнение в тексте вопроса

Comment: Ну, берем start_date и end_date Васи, по очереди проверяем для каждого сотрудника что start_date Сотрудника <= start_date Васи <= end_date Сотрудника ИЛИ start_date Сотрудника <= end_date Васи <= end_date Сотрудника. Вопрос в том как конкретно это надо в Django написать?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров
Скорее не в джанго, а в питоне. Не могу понять, как сравнивать именно со следующей строкой. Сам синтаксис не могу понять, что ли. Вот на такое только мозгов хватило. во вьюхе:
 vac = Vacation.objects.all()
    for person in vac:
        if person.fio == 'Петя':
             result = "Петя нашелся! c ID = "+str(person.id)
Так же могу сравнить даты в пределах 1 строки. Но как с последующими не понимаю.

Comment: решил. надо использовать вложенный цикл for